# How do I pass the full file name, including spaces, from the windows registry as a parameter to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing, registry

What I'd like to do: Add an entry to a Windows 10 context menu for specific file types (e.g. .mp4) that allows me to search for the file name on a website (in my case, IMDB). I got the entry to show up fine, but file names cut off after any space character.

Question: How do I pass the full file name, including spaces, from the windows registry as a parameter to a batch file?

.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.mp4\shell\Search IMDB\command]
@="\"C:\\test.bat\" \"%1\""
```

test.bat

```
SET a="%~n1"
SET z=https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title=
SET zz=%z%%a%
start "" %zz%
```

For a file name like *movie.mp4* this works. However, file name *cool movie.mp4* will in this case open a search page for "cool" which I'm afraid does not help me.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the spaces with + signs.

According to https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html that should be something like

```
SET zzz=%zz: =+%
```

Answer (score 0):

The batch file should be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "Name=%~n1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Name=!Name:%%=%%25!"
set "Name=!Name: =%%20!"
start "" "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title=!Name!"
endlocal
endlocal
```

First, read my answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains in detail what is the difference between `set variable="value"` and `set "variable=value"`. The latter is the recommended syntax.

Second, a URL must be [percent-encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-bytes). A normal space character must be encoded with `%20` in a URL. The batch file above does that. It percent-encodes first also `%` in name by `%25`.

**Note:** The entire URL is not correct percent-encoded if the string assigned to the environment variable `Name` contains other characters than   and `%` which need to be percent-encoded for a valid URL too.

Third, the character `%` must be escaped in a batch file with one more `%` to be interpreted as literal character even within a double quoted argument string.